# Adding Results from an array, within an array

Tags: php, sum

I'm trying to add gq_numplayers from both of these arrays together and echo the total. Can anyone shed some light on how i might do that?

Thanks.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
            [dedicated] => d
            [game_descr] => Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
            [game_dir] => csgo
            [gq_address] => xx.xx.xx.xx
            [gq_dedicated] => d
            [gq_gametype] => 
            [gq_hostname] => CS Server
            [gq_joinlink] => steam://connect/
            [gq_mapname] => de_dust2
            [gq_maxplayers] => 24
            [gq_mod] => csgo
            [gq_numplayers] => 1
            [gq_online] => 1
            [gq_password] => 0
            [gq_port] => 27017
            [gq_protocol] => source
            [gq_transport] => udp
            [gq_type] => csgo
            [hostname] => CS Server
            [map] => de_dust2
            [max_players] => 24
            [num_bots] => 0
            [num_players] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cd_announcer_version] => 2.3
            [coop] => 0
            [deathmatch] => 1
            [decalfrequency] => 15
            [dedicated] => d
            [game_descr] => Team Fortress
            [game_dir] => tf
            [gq_address] => xx.xx.xx.xx
            [gq_dedicated] => d
            [gq_gametype] => 
            [gq_hostname] => TF2 Server
            [gq_joinlink] => steam://connect/
            [gq_mapname] => mvm_rottenburg
            [gq_maxplayers] => 6
            [gq_mod] => tf
            [gq_numplayers] => 0
            [gq_online] => 1
            [gq_password] => 0
            [gq_port] => 27019
            [gq_protocol] => source
            [gq_transport] => udp
        )
)
```

I've been able to pull individual values from each array, by but i can't add them together :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a foreach loop to loop over every element:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($arr as $x) {
  $total += $x['gq_numplayers'];
}

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the name of whichever variable is being dumped there, but presume it's $foo, try

```
echo $foo[1]['gq_numplayers'] + $foo[2]['gq_numplayers'];
```